# Alternative to Azure Key Vault provider in Always Encrypted SQL Server for applications running on Linux

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-keyvault, always-encrypted

To utilize Always Encrypted feature in SQL Server, impleting Azure Key Vault provider is the most convenient option. However, it has a dependency with the Azure cloud network.

Azure Key Vault cannot be used for on-premise intranet only deployments. When the application is running on Windows Server, any Windows comptibale provider like MSSQL_CERTIFICATE_STORE can be used. But if the application is running on Linux server, there is no provider available.

What is the recommend solution to use a key store provider for Always Encrypted SQL Server on Linux machines?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use ODBC Driver 17 for always encrypted SQL Server running on Linux machine. You can download the driver from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

This [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-always-encrypted-with-the-odbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15) will help you to understand all the prerequisites and implementation steps.

Comment: I'm already using ODBC driver 17. Azure key vault is still required.